# What is the meaning of sign ':' in javascript

Tags: javascript

When I was creating website, I find code like this

```
javascript:history.go(-1)
```

What is the definition of sign ':'?

Comment: It is a label statement: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label

Comment: `javascript:` is the pseudo scheme for injecting JavaScript into a webpage

Comment: The colons, in your code, are not part of JavaScript. It's part of the location protocol, so things like `http:`, `ftp:`, `javascript:`, and `gopher:` all used colon to separate the protocol from address.

Comment: Probably a URL for injecting javascript into the page

Comment: thank you, all. why I get minus ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the inline script. When you use javascript in html you use `javascript:your_method()` or simply `yourmethod()`

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">click</a>
```

So, as @nhahtdh `javascript:` is the pseudo scheme for injecting javascript.

And as @JackPattishall The colons, in your code, are not part of JavaScript. It's part of the location protocol, so things like `http:, ftp:, javascript:, and gopher:` all used colon to separate the protocol from address.

Answer (score 0):

In that situation, which I presume you see in the 'href' or 'on lock' attribute of an A tag, 'javascript' is a protocol. Browsers historically execute JavaScript in the address bar if it's prefaced with that protocol. It's the way bookmarklets work.